# Where can I find illustrations online depicting Idrisi's coffer in the Queen's chamber in the "Khufu" pyramid

Tags: ancient-history, archaeology, architecture, historical-research, pyramids

I believe I have found sufficient evidence that points to a block of stone, not necessarily a coffer as stated by Idrisi, being inside the niche in the Queen's Chamber blocking the entrance to the dead-end passage.

I have been attempting to obtain illustrations online from early travelers to examine, so far without success. Does anyone know where I could source such an illustration online, preferably not paywalled?

While on the topic of the pyramids, does anyone have a theory about the insect remains found by Vyse in the relieving chamber? I was struck by it's apparent similarities to our modern-day graphite powder, and wonder if it could have been used in a similar fashion....

Comment: I revised your title; please correct any errors I made.  We are a Q&A site, and it works better if the title asks a question.  I'd also advise that asking two questions in the body may not get you the answer s - might be more effective to ask two separate, small, focused questions.

Comment: Details and links about the sources you have already consulted would be extremely helpful.